# How to exit C++ program with any exit code?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my own OS shell for a school assignment, and one of the requirements is to allow the user to specify an exit code when exiting the program by stating "exit [n]". However, it seems as though the exit function in the standard library will not permit any integer past 255 to be an exit code. For example:

```
exit(255);
```

prints "Process finished with exit code 255".

```
exit(256);
```

prints "Process finished with exit code 0".

```
exit(257);
```

prints "Process finished with exit code 1".

And so on. As you can see, the error code loops back around to 0 once the code exceeds 255. Is there any way to get rid of this exit code cap? What is going on here? How can I get the exit code to be any integer?

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS) the exit code is only stored in a single byte.

Comment: There are only three **portable** values for `exit(value)`: `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The first two "mean" that the program completed successfully, and the third one means something went wrong. To get the definitions for `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, use `#include <cstdlib>`. Compilers are allowed to support additional values, but, obviously, using them requires that you know what your compiler does.